# Blender, UV Layer, Image and Python

Tags: python, textures, blender

I'm trying to access UV Layer in Blender from Python and basically API returns UV Layer only as a string. Thing is I want to assign new Image object to current UV Layer ( I use TexFace on the side of material ) and then just bake lighting. All meshes are currently unwrapped, the only thing which is missing is an Image and I have no idea how to add image I will bake lighting to from Python level.

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is (if you are using Blender 2.49b) set the image of the Texture object and the uvlayer property of the MTex object.